# Retrieving Office 365 Exchange Quarantine Sender and Receiver with Powershell

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I've been trying to retrieve the basic information with Powershell from Office 365 Exchange, but I can't seem to get all I want in one command.

If I use:

```
Get-QuarantineMessage -SenderAddress send@domain1.tld -RecipientAddress receive@domain2.tld | Select-Object Identity,SenderAddress,RecipientAddress,Subject,QuarantineTypes,Direction,Expires
```

I get everything I want except the RecipientAddress:

```
Identity         : eafc9e23-8c21-7a40-2d92-41a9a402abe5\e62c7c5b-7da4-2b79-        
e5f4-b902fc927429
SenderAddress    : send@domain1.tld
RecipientAddress : {}
Subject          : Downtown Events
QuarantineTypes  : Spam
Direction        : Inbound
Expires          : 5/3/2019 1:00:00 PM
```

I have to use the same command twice in a for loop to get it:

```
(Get-QuarantineMessage -SenderAddress send@domain1.tld -RecipientAddress receive@domain2.tld).Identity | ForEach-Object {Get-QuarantineMessage -Identity $_ | Select-Object Identity,SenderAddress,RecipientAddress,Subject,QuarantineTypes,Direction,Expires} 

Identity         : eafc9e23-8c21-7a40-2d92-41a9a402abe5\e62c7c5b-7da4-2b79-e5f4-b902fc927429
SenderAddress    : send@domain1.tld
RecipientAddress : {receive@domain2.tld}
Subject          : Downtown Events
QuarantineTypes  : Spam
Direction        : Inbound
Expires          : 5/3/2019 1:00:00 PM
```

I feel like there has to be a better/more elegant way of doing this then running the same command twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot test this myself, but it seems to me you already have the `RecipientAddress` and are using it in the call.

Perhaps then, this may save you from calling the same command twice:

```
$recipient = 'receive@domain2.tld'
Get-QuarantineMessage -SenderAddress send@domain1.tld -RecipientAddress $recipient | 
    Select-Object Identity,SenderAddress,
                  @{Name = 'RecipientAddress'; Expression = {$recipient}},
                  Subject,QuarantineTypes,Direction,Expires
```

Comment: Thanks that worked great.  Though could you explain how the @{} part works?